# Application.Volatile issue when outside of the Excel document

Tags: vba, excel

This code works inside of the referenced Excel document.

```
Application.Volatile
ThisWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties("CLIENT").Value = CLIENT
ThisWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties("Project").Value = PROJECT
ThisWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties("DATE").Value = Date
ThisWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties("Drawing/Job No").Value = JOB_NUMBER & " / " & NAMCON
ThisWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties("Drawn By").Value = DRAWN_BY
```

But it fails when I try to open up the document and edit the properties. It fails at Application.Volatile. I must be missing something. If I can do this in the referenced Excel document, surely I should be able to open the file and send an instruction.

```
'excell api
Dim excelApp As Excel.Application
Dim targetWB As Workbook
Dim targetRange As Range
    'EXCELL , CUSTOM PROP

Sub PR_RUN()
    Call COPYFILE
    Call WRITE_TO_PRFORM
End Sub

Sub COPYFILE()
    JOB_NO_LP = "XXXX"
    Filepath = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\ADB NEW TEST\"
Dim SourceFile, DestinationFile
    SourceFile = "C:\TEST\XXXX - PRODUCTION FORM MARCO.xlsm" ' Define source file name.
    DestinationFile = Filepath & "PRODUCTION\01_CUT FILES\" & JOB_NO_LP & " - PRODUCTION FORM" & ".xlsm"    ' Define target file name."
    FileCopy SourceFile, DestinationFile ' Copy source to target.
End Sub

Sub WRITE_TO_PRFORM()
Dim excelApp As Excel.Application
Dim targetWB As Workbook
Dim targetRange As Range
    'Create new Excel Application
    Set excelApp = New Excel.Application
    'Keep hidden
    excelApp.Visible = False
    MsgBox "JOB_NO_LP: " & JOB_NO_LP
    Set targetWB = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(Filepath & "PRODUCTION\01_CUT FILES\" & JOB_NO_LP & " - PRODUCTION FORM" & ".xlsm") ' update with locaton
    'Keep hidden
    excelApp.Visible = False

' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' ghost Excel processes (may not be need with end statement)
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Dim thisSheet As Worksheet
    Set thisSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    thisSheet.Activate

'-----------------------------------------------------
' CUSTOM PROP SET
'-----------------------------------------------------
    Application.Volatile
    ThisWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties("CLIENT").Value = CLIENT
    ThisWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties("Project").Value = PROJECT
    ThisWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties("DATE").Value = Date
    ThisWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties("Drawing/Job No").Value = JOB_NUMBER & " / " & NAMCON
    ThisWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties("Drawn By").Value = DRAWN_BY

'-----------------------------------------------------
'Close Save workbook
'-----------------------------------------------------
    excelApp.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    'excelApp.DisplayAlerts = True
    'Close Excel App
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    excelApp.Quit
Dim BruteForce As String
    BruteForce = "TASKKILL /F /IM excel.exe"
    Shell BruteForce, vbHide
End Sub
```

Comment: Where are you trying to run this from?

Comment: From solidworks , vba Marco , am try to pass information from the program to the property of the Excell document

Comment: Application.Volatile only works inside a UDF, not a sub: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-volatile-method-excel .Why do you think you need it anyway? It's used to force cells to refresh on the worksheet change event, I don't think it's relevant to what you're trying to do

Comment: as the referenced excel document is marco enabled and has a UDF function to apply the custom properties to select cells with the the first sheet, once the properties have been pass to the excel document,